# ¿Por qué me sale el error en mysqli_query() Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given on line 16?

Tags: php, mysql

Validación de datos, estoy creando un formulario que me valide los datos pero me sale el error de que debo declarar la variable.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español! Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender como funciona este sitio y cómo realizar preguntas aceptadas por la comunidad. En tu caso te falta un [example] pues no nos dices ni muestras apenas nada y no somos adivinos (aunque tengamos google, al igual que tu).

Comment: Aun así, me parece intuir que en la línea 16 del archivo donde se está realizando la consulta tienes una instrucción `mysqli_query()` que debe contener algun tipo de dato que es **null**, y mi consejo es que revises esa línea e investiges que valor le estas pasando a la consulta, pues al ser `null` indica que no contiene ningun valor (si se trata de una variable).  Supongamos que tienes esto: `mysqli_query($var)`. Pues esa variable $var es `null` o bien vacia, no definida antes quizas. No se, estoy diciendo esto al tuntun, por si acierto. Como ves, necesitamos ver tu codigo para ayudarte bien

Comment: Si, subiré el código cuando pase el tiempo para hacer la siguiente pregunta,.
sin querer hice la pregunta  y le di a enviar sin el código.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Todo apunta a que estas aplicando la función mysqli_query sobre una consulta vacía.

mysqli_query($query);

$query debe contener la cadena de consulta SQL.